# Robocopy Parameters Options

Tags: windows, robocopy

I want to copy with robocopy a directory and his subfolders.

I wan’t to exclude some subfolders and all files in the root directory.

Now I copy the directories in different jobs, but I only wan’t to have one job

```
$roboOptions = @("/e", "/xo", "/r:2", "/w:2", "/log+:$logFile")

#* Copy to Share2

# &robocopy $buildDrop $copyTargetMaster $roboOptions


#* Copy Share1

&robocopy   $buildDrop"\Client" $copyTarget"\Client" $roboOptions
&robocopy   $buildDrop"\Database" $copyTarget"\Database" $roboOptions
&robocopy   $buildDrop"\dbscripts" $copyTarget"\dbscripts" $roboOptions
&robocopy   $buildDrop"\EA" $copyTarget"\EA" $roboOptions
&robocopy   $buildDrop"\Jobs" $copyTarget"\Jobs" $roboOptions
&robocopy   $buildDrop"\replication" $copyTarget"\replication" $roboOptions
&robocopy   $buildDrop"\server" $copyTarget"\server" $roboOptions
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I do it:

```
@ECHO off
>nul 2>nul robocopy
if errorlevel 9009 (
  ECHO ROBOCOPY is not installed.
) else (
  ECHO Starting 1-way backup of MEDIA(M:) to BACKUP(G:)...
    robocopy.exe M:\ G:\ *.* /E /PURGE /SEC /NP /NJH /NJS^
 /XD "$RECYCLE.BIN" "System Volume Information" /TEE /R:5 /COPYALL^
 /LOG:from_MEDIA_to_BACKUP.log
  ECHO Finished with backup.
)    
pause
```

Comment: Shouldn't you add the robocopy to the 'else'-part of the code? No use executing it if it isn't there.

Comment: Sure, but if its not there it wont run anyway.  I'll adjust my answer to reflect that change.